# How does a child ViewModel prompt the parent ViewModel to navigate away in Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: c#, navigation, caliburn.micro

In Caliburn.Micro I have a Shell ViewModel that has 3 IShell properties corresponding to 3 content controls in the associated View. They are 'Full', 'List' and 'Detail'. 'Full' sits above the other two and is as wide as the host Form. 'List' is on the left hand 1 row down and 'Detail' is in the same row as 'List' 1 column to the right.

When the app starts, a Login ViewModel is bound to 'Full' and nothing is bound to the other two. The screen shows only the Login screen. The user should login, and when complete the 'Full' content control should switch from displaying the Login ViewModel, to an AccountViewModel.

For that to work I need the LoginViewModel to tell the ShellViewModel (its parent) to navigate to AccountViewModel.

How do I do that?

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
{
    #region Fields

    private string _title = "License Manager";

    private Conductor<IScreen> _fullFrameConductor;
    private Conductor<IScreen> _listFrameConductor;
    private Conductor<IScreen> _detailFrameConductor;

    #endregion

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        _fullFrameConductor = new Conductor<IScreen>();
        _listFrameConductor = new Conductor<IScreen>();
        _detailFrameConductor = new Conductor<IScreen>();

        FullFrame = Framework.GetContainer().Resolve<LoginViewModel>();            
    }

    #region Properties

    public string Title { get => _title; set => _title = value; }

    public IScreen FullFrame
    {
        get { return _fullFrameConductor.ActiveItem; }
        set {
            _fullFrameConductor.ActivateItem(value);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(FullFrame));
        }
    }

    public IScreen ListFrame
    {
        get { return _listFrameConductor.ActiveItem; }
        set {
            _listFrameConductor.ActivateItem(value);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(ListFrame));
        }
    }

    public IScreen DetailFrame
    {
        get { return _detailFrameConductor.ActiveItem; }
        set {
            _detailFrameConductor.ActivateItem(value);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(DetailFrame));
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region Commands

    public void ShowProducts()
    {
        ListFrame = Framework.GetContainer().Resolve<ProductListViewModel>();
        DetailFrame = Framework.GetContainer().Resolve<ProductViewModel>();
    }

    public void ShowLicenses()
    {
        ListFrame = Framework.GetContainer().Resolve<LicenseListViewModel>();
        DetailFrame = Framework.GetContainer().Resolve<LicenseViewModel>();
    }


    #endregion
}


public class LicenseViewModel : Screen
{

    public void Login()
    {
        // This should process the login and then tell the Shell it is done
        // then the shell should navigate to the Account ViewModel sharing
        // the user info with the AccountViewModel via a memory cache

        // How do I alert the screen ViewModel causing it to close this viewmodel
        // without causing a threading problem?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Event Aggregator to communicate between LoginViewModel and ShellViewModel. You can read more on Event Aggregator here.

First, you need to create a Message Class

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessMessage
{
    public bool IsValidLogin{get;set;}
}
```

Then next step is to use EventAggregator to notify the ShellViewModel from the LicenseViewModel .

```
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
 public LicenseViewModel (IEventAggregator eventAggregator) 
 {
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
 }

 public void Login()
 {
    _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(new AuthenticationSuccessMessage{IsValidLogin=true});
 }
```

The final step is to subscribe to the Events in ShellViewModel.

```
public class ShellViewModel:Screen, IHandle<AuthenticationSuccessMessage>
{
   private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

   public ShellViewModel:Screen(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
    }
    void Handle<AuthenticationSuccessMessage>(AuthenticationSuccessMessage message)
    {
        if(message.IsValidLogin)
        {
            // Do Task
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more on Event Aggregators [here](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator).

**Update** : Do not forget to subscribe to Event Aggregator in ShellViewModel.

Comment: You need to subscribe to get the message in the `ShellViewModel`.

Comment: @JackHughes Thanks for pointing it out. Somehow i missed it. Have updated the code now